# problem with access query and operator not working

Tags: c#, ms-access

i have a search form where user can type in and search for records. the search keyword in the search bar are in this form: **smooth,wood,38**
Now the actual problem is that, when user type in for one keyword a record is returned and when he type in for a second keyword, a record is returned but the old record which is not matching to the search is also returned.
if he type in for **38,wood so two records** are returned but when he type in red, logically only one record should be returned but it dont and it **returned the blue one as well.**
*Every time the user type in for a search_keyword or 2nd keyword,3rd keyword the result should be filtered according to the search word and unfortunately it is not doing like that*.
table1 structure like this:

```
id         path              name            search_keyword
1          c:\my picture\    red door           red;
2          c:\my picture\    red door           38;
3          c:\my picture\    red door           wood; 
4          c:\my picture\    red door           2500;
5          c:\my picture\    red door           smooth
6          c:\my picture\    blue door          blue ;
7          c:\my picture\    blue door           38;
8          c:\my picture\    blue door           wood; 
9          c:\my picture\    blue door           2600;
19         c:\my picture\    blue door           smooth;
```

this table contain the search keyword where the user can type in for search_keyword and can get the result filter (multiple search key-word);
suppose he type in starting **smooth,wood 38** so both the result should be displayed now when he type **red/blue or 2600/2500 then the result should be one.**

the query look like this:

```
select Distinct name from table1 where search_keyword like '%smooth%' And '% wood %' and '%red%' order by name
```

following code:

```
    publi override list<result> retrunsearch(string search)
{
string[] search = pQuery.Split(',');
List <result> myresult = new List<result>();
for (int i = 1; i < search.Length; i++)
                {

   StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.Append(
                string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT name,path FROM table1 WHERE search_keyword LIKE '%{0};%'", search[0])
            );

            // Add extra keywords

            for (int i = 1; i < search.Length; i++)
            {
                query.Append(string.Format(" And '%{0};%'", search[i]));
            }


            // Add order by
            query.Append(" ORDER BY name");

            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query.ToString(), sqlconConnection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (OleDbDataReader sdaResult0 = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                while (sdaResult0.Read())
                {
                    result restult1= new result();
                    result1.name   = sdaResult0.String(0);
                    myresult.add(result1);
                }

                sdaResult0.Close();

}
}

return myresult;
}

public class result{

public result()
{
}

public string name{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It seems like a merge error. Just remove the outer loop.

Comment: @SlavaGu I have took out the outer loop and still i am getting the mix up result :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask Access' database engine to run this query ...

```
select Distinct name from table1 where search_keyword like '%smooth%' And '% wood %' and '%red%' order by name
```

... I think the results it gives you will be the same as if you asked it to run this query ...

```
select Distinct name
from table1
where
    search_keyword like '%smooth%'
    And True
    and True
order by name
```

You have to tell it which field you're comparing against, and the type of comparison you want, for each ANDed condition in the WHERE clause.

```
select Distinct name
from table1
where
    search_keyword like '%smooth%'
    And search_keyword like '% wood %'
    and search_keyword like '%red%'
order by name
```

However, looking at the sample data for table1, no records contain all three of your search strings in the search_keyword field.  So perhaps you really want OR instead of AND between those WHERE clause conditons:

```
select Distinct [name]
from table1
where
    search_keyword like '%smooth%'
    OR search_keyword like '% wood %'
    OR search_keyword like '%red%'
order by [name]
```

I also enclosed name in square brackets because name is a reserved word in MS Access.

**Edit**: Also, I wonder whether you really want the spaces before and after wood.  If not, try it this way:

```
OR search_keyword like '%wood%'
```

**Edit2**: Since your comment indicated you can try queries in Access directly, try these two and let us know what happens when you run them in Access instead of from c#.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT [name]
    FROM table1
    WHERE
        search_keyword ALike '%smooth%'
        AND search_keyword ALike '%wood%'
        AND search_keyword ALike '%red%'
    ORDER BY [name]

    SELECT DISTINCT [name]
    FROM table1
    WHERE
        search_keyword ALike '%smooth%'
        OR search_keyword ALike '%wood%'
        OR search_keyword ALike '%red%'
    ORDER BY [name]
```

Based on the sample data you showed us, the first query should return no records and the second should return several.

Comment: when i put the Column Name then no result is returned. i have tried this in the access and if you put and `column name and column_name` then no result is returned. But if you do like this : `Select name from table1 where search_keyword like '%smooth%' and '%wood%' ` then value is returned but the record is filter only by the first and i.e '%wood%', if i put or then the result is not exactly to search_keyword.

Comment: @safi I added more information to my answer.  You may have been mislead by the wildcard character issue with Access.  I used the ALike (instead of Like) comparison so Access would accept the ANSI % wildcard character instead of \* character.  We can talk more about this if you want.

Comment: i have read your earlier post as well and i have used alike but in access if i mentioned like `and Column_name like %blue% and Column_name like %red%` then access do not conside it. so i have to avoid the 2nd column_name Mentioned. The edited 2 section has solved the problem.